# SwiftUI if let inside View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want a if let statement inside a `View`.

```
@ObservedObject var person: Person?
 var body: some View {
      if person != nil {
        // this works
      }
      if let p = person {
        // Compiler error
      }
    }
```

**Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'**

Comment: Nope, that's not currently supported. The only kind of control flow you can have in a view builder is `if...else`.

Comment: so I should forcecast i those situations?

Comment: using force cast is not a good solution. It's better to check with nil and handle it in if-else

Comment: At the moment you can either force cast/unwrap or call another property or function that isn't directly in an `@ViewBuilder` scope so you can use normal control flow like `if let`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*2022 Update*

You can just use normal Swift `if let`:

```swift
if let pieceOfData = pieceOfData {
  // now it's guaranteed
} else {
  // now it's not
}
```

*Previous Answer*

Or you can create your own `IfLet` view builder:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct IfLet<Value, Content, NilContent>: View where Content: View, NilContent: View {

    let value: Value?
    let contentBuilder: (Value) -> Content
    let nilContentBuilder: () -> NilContent

    init(_ optionalValue: Value?, @ViewBuilder whenPresent contentBuilder: @escaping (Value) -> Content, @ViewBuilder whenNil nilContentBuilder: @escaping () -> NilContent) {
        self.value = optionalValue
        self.contentBuilder = contentBuilder
        self.nilContentBuilder = nilContentBuilder
    }

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if value != nil {
                contentBuilder(value!)
            } else {
                nilContentBuilder()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension IfLet where NilContent == EmptyView {

    init(_ optionalValue: Value?, @ViewBuilder whenPresent contentBuilder: @escaping (Value) -> Content) {
        self.init(optionalValue, whenPresent: contentBuilder, whenNil: { EmptyView() })
    }
}
```

Using this, you can now do the following:

```swift
var body: some View {
    IfLet(pieceOfData) { realData in
        // realData is no longer optional
    }
}
```

Want to respond if your optional is `nil`?

```swift
var body: some View {
    IfLet(pieceOfData, whenPresent: { realData in
        // realData is no longer optional
        DataView(realData)
    }, whenNil: {
        EmptyDataView()
    })
}
```

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer it should be updated to show that if let is now supported

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the notation requested in code snapshot is not allowed, at least for now, but the intended result is possible to achieve with the following very **simple approach - extract control flow into function**:

```
var person: Person? // actually @ObservedObject does not allowed optional
var body: some View {
    VStack {
         if person != nil {
           // same as before
         }
         personViewIfExists() // << just extract it in helper function
    }
}

private func personViewIfExists() -> some View { // generates view conditionally
    if let p = person {
      return ExistedPersonView(person: p) // << just for demo
    }
}
```

on some conditions also the following variant of function might be required (although it produces the same result)

```
private func personViewIfExists() -> some View {
    if let p = person {
      return AnyView(ExistedPersonView(person: p))
    }
    return AnyView(EmptyView())
}
```

Comment: If possible, one should avoid using `AnyView` in SwiftUI, and instead use the `@ViewBuilder` wrapper.

Comment: For the above comment, see Demystify SwiftUI: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/

Answer (score 3):

The simpler approach is to just use `.map()`

It will show a `UserProfile` if `user` has a value, and nothing if `user` is nil:

```
var user: User? 
var body: some View {
  user.map { UserProfile(user: $0) }
}
```

If you want to provide a default view for nil value, you can just use the nil-coalescing operator:

```
var user: User? 
var body: some View {
  user.map { UserProfile(user: $0) } ?? UserProfile(user: .default) 
}
```

However this requires the two views to be of the same type, and in practice if they're of the same type you're better off just writing `UserProfile(user: $0 ?? .default)`.

What's interesting is the case where the two views are not of the same type. You could just erase their type by wrapping them in `AnyView`, but it does get a bit cumbersome and difficult to read at this point:

```
var user: User? 
var body: some View {
  user.map { AnyView(UserProfile(user: $0)) } ?? AnyView(Text("Not logged in"))
}
```

So in this case, my preferred approach is to use a custom `IfLet` struct (same name as Procrastin8's, but a different implementation and syntax) that allows me to write something like this, which I find very clear in intent and easy to type.

```
var user: User? 
var body: some View {
  IfLet(user) { UserProfile(user: $0) } 
    .else { Text("Not logged in") }
}
```

The code for my `IfLet` component is as follows.

```
struct IfLet<Wrapped, IfContent> : View where IfContent: View {
  let optionalValue: Wrapped?
  let contentBuilder: (Wrapped) -> IfContent

  init(_ optionalValue: Wrapped?, @ViewBuilder contentBuilder: @escaping (Wrapped) -> IfContent) {
    self.optionalValue = optionalValue
    self.contentBuilder = contentBuilder
  }

  var body: some View {
    optionalValue.map { contentBuilder($0) }
  }

  func `else`<ElseContent:View>(@ViewBuilder contentBuilder: @escaping () -> ElseContent) -> some View {
    if optionalValue == nil {
      return AnyView(contentBuilder())
    } else {
      return AnyView(self)
    }
  }
}
```

Enjoy!