# Handling Optional Values in SwiftUI Text View: Best Practices?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, option-type, instruments

I've often found myself in a situation where I have optional data (such as optional properties coming back from an API) that I want to display in a SwiftUI View if they exist, and skip over if they are `nil`.

Recently, a senior developer told me I should not have conditional logic in my swiftUI views.  I used to check optionality on properties in my ViewModel within the View using `if let`. Now I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910083/handling-optionals-nil-values-in-swiftui-views-using-if-let-in-swiftui) I can see there are a few different ways to do this.

1. `if property != nil { Text(property!) }`
2. `if let unwrappedProperty = property { Text(unwrappedProperty)`
3. `property.map { Text($0) }`
4. Handling the optional property in a helper function that wraps the result in `AnyView()`

```
private func optionalView(_ property: property)
{
   if let unwrappedProperty = property {
       return AnyView(Text(unwrappedProperty) })
   } else {
       return AnyView(EmptyView())
   }
}
```

5. Provide a default value using `Text(property ?? "")` (this one is different from the rest as this will create a Text View with an empty string, whereas the others will not create the view at all.

So all of these options work, and I was curious **Which is preferred?**

First, I wanted to check the performance of each option, so I created a load test based on [this great article](https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-performance-battle-anyview-vs-group-55bf852158df).

What I found was that all the options render at the same performance, except for option five which renders about 7% faster.  This makes sense to me as in option #5 the TextView is always being rendered and my test isn't about state changes, just optionality.  I wouldn't use that option in the real world because as your model increases in size you'd have to hard code hundreds of default values.

So if the performance from options 1-4 is the same, which is preferred?

My inclination is to believe that #3 `property.map { Text($0) }` is the cleanest and most clear option so that is what I have been using.

However, I'm also wondering if perhaps I'm missing a bigger paradigm issue; Should I never be observing optional properties in my view at all?

If your API has the potential to return null values for properties, should I have an interface that manages that before reaching the ViewModel?  I'm not sure how I would handle that.

My end goal is to have a modular view that is able to handle a dataset with various missing pieces of data and leave those out of the View Hierarchy.

Comment: In #1, `property` would still be an optional, unless you use `!`, so it doesn't work as is. #4 is a bad idea because of its use of `AnyView` -- look into `@ViewBuilder` to see how to modify it to avoid `AnyView`. #2, 3, 5 are all reasonable. "Which is preferred?" is going to be opinion-based.

Comment: "Should I never be observing optional properties in my view at all?" For most applications, even if it were desirable (which I don't think it necessarily is), it would probably be extremely challenging to design an API where one could avoid optionals in views all the time.

Comment: #5 with a version of [bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021722/swiftui-optional-textfield) instead. The only data type where I haven't been able to get an acceptable solution is `Date` because the `DatePicker` makes the variable appear to have a value.